# gridview link button redirect to another page

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="Sevkiyat Bulunamadı"
    class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" 
    AllowPaging="True" 
    OnPageIndexChanged="GridView1_PageIndexChanged" 
    OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
    OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound" 
    OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
    AllowSorting="True" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
                Teklif İste
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="yetkiliad" ItemStyle-CssClass="yetkiliad" HeaderText="yetkiliad" SortExpression="yetkiliad" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="yetkilisoyad" ItemStyle-CssClass="yetkilisoyad" HeaderText="yetkilisoyad" SortExpression="yetkilisoyad" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="firmaismi" ItemStyle-CssClass="firmaismi" HeaderText="firmaismi" SortExpression="firmaismi" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="telefon" ItemStyle-CssClass="telefon" HeaderText="telefon" SortExpression="telefon" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="adres" ItemStyle-CssClass="adres" HeaderText="adres" SortExpression="adres" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mail" ItemStyle-CssClass="mail" HeaderText="mail" SortExpression="mail" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton Text="View" ID="lnkView" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <RowStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I have code like this. I cant find how to redirect when click view button on each row. I mean when i clicked second row's view it shoudl be redirected related link with second row. Could you help me about it

Comment: How does the link, the one you want to follow when clicking on the linkbutton, look like? You don't seem to have it in the code at all.

Comment: I don't know what am i going to write in background. I tried selected index change for redirect but i cant redirect according to spesific row.

Comment: protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
        }
    }

Comment: No, I mean the URL that you are going to use, do you have it? And please don't post code in comments. If it is relevant, it should be edited into the question

Comment: I tried this but i dont know how to redirect according to row index

Comment: oww let me expain my secon rows firmaname databound + .aspx is going to new page for that row

Comment: forexample if firmaname data is kemal, the redirected page is going to be kemal.aspx

Answer (score 2):

No need to create a `LinkButton` inside the `asp:TemplateField`. Just use an `asp:HyperLinkField` like this

```
<asp:HyperLinkField Text="View" 
    DataNavigateUrlFields="firmaname" 
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/{0}.aspx" />
```

Comment: Actually i need if i click second row's view and if that rows datafiled's name is kemal after click event completed it should be redirect kemal.aspx file

Comment: That kind of logic should be done in the ItemDataBound event. Research the itemDataBound event for the grid. In the ItemDataBound you will find your hyperlink control and do logic to switch the url based on the scenario.

Comment: this is the correct way. editing your answer a bit to remove minor bugs. id and runat="server" are not the properties of `asp:HyperLinkField`

Comment: Gridview uses RowDataBound. ItemDataBound is used in other controls like Repeater or ListView

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server"  OnClick="lnkView_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>View</asp:LinkButton>


protected void lnkView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int Id = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
     Response.Redirect("Foo.aspx?Id=" + Id);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what the relation is between redirected page and row?

Comment: Actually i need if i click second row's view and if that rows datafiled's name  which calll firmaismi , is kemal after click event completed it should be redirect kemal.aspx file this is relationship between them.

Comment: Thats not a good way to work with, you should use Id. There is aproach like that but its too advanced for you. use Id to distinguish your rows

Comment: now use Id to distinguish, later you can research about maproute which is what you are trying to accomplish. even in that you will use Id to distinguish rows.